# Seaborn boxplot with confidence intervals for the mean

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot, confidence-interval

I'm trying to visualize a boxplot using Seaborn with an addition of mean and the 95% confidence interval for that mean. I'm able to plot the mean but have no idea how to proceed from there to get the confidence intervals.

This is what I have currently:

```
ax = sns.boxplot(x="Player type", y="Attitude", data=df, palette="Blues_d", medianprops={'color':'white'}, showmeans=True, meanprops={"marker":"s","markerfacecolor":"white", "markeredgecolor":"black"})
```

Here is the plot that is currently produced:

[image: current plot]

This is an example with what I'd like to do (mean + confidence intervals as black in the figure):

[image: example of desired plot]

If this is not possible with Seaborn's boxplot I'm happy to hear any other suggestion you may have to accomplish this!

Comment: The easiest would be to set `notch=True` in `sns.boxplot(...., notch=True)`. It's a parameter which seaborn passes to `plt.boxplot()`. If you don't want such a notch, you could add errorbars on top of the boxplot.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for an answer for a similar type of problem, I did a not-so-pretty workaround by plotting the boxplot and showing the mean, and then on top plotted a barplot which allows adding 95% bootstrapped confidence intervals for the mean and just made the barplot transparent.

```
ax = sns.boxplot(ax=axes[0], x="Player type", y="Attitude Likert scale [1-7]", data=player_data_easier, palette="Blues", medianprops={'color':'white'}, showmeans=True, meanprops={"marker":"s","markerfacecolor":"white", "markeredgecolor":"black"})
kwargs = {'alpha':0}
ax = sns.barplot(ax=axes[0], x="Player type", y="Attitude Likert scale [1-7]", data=player_data_easier, palette="Blues", capsize=.1, n_boot=1000, ci=95, errwidth=2, **kwargs)
```

Which produces this:

[image]